# Can anyone provide BBC music properties?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, linked-data

Can Anyone Provide Me List of All  BBC Music Properties ?

i.e coreconcepts/placeOfBirth , coreconcepts/eventPlace
 etc.

or Link Where I Can Find These Properties.

Comment: You may also find [Semantic web application - using BBC Sports ontology](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19016270/1281433) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In general, resource request questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow.  The close reasons include:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

It's actually pretty easy to *find* the resources that you're looking for.  In fact, the first hit in a Google search for `BBC music ontology` is the [BBC's ontologies page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies), which is what you're looking for.  There at least one other question that asks how to use some of thi content:

- [Semantic web application - using BBC Sports ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19016270/1281433)

However, it may be useful to see exactly what you can do with the information that they provide.  First, they note:

> This site provides access to the ontologies the BBC is using to
>   support its audience facing applications such as BBC Sport, BBC
>   Education, BBC Music, News projects and more. These ontologies form
>   the basis of our Linked Data Platform.
>
> If you would like to access an RDF Turtle version of an ontology,
>   simply add .ttl to the end of an ontology URL.

Then they list a bunch of ontologies.  I'm not sure which ones are used in the BBC Music related stuff, though the following look like good candidates:

> - [Core Concepts Ontology](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/coreconcepts)
>     The generic BBC ontology for people, places,events, organisations, themes which represent things that make
>     sense across the BBC. This model is meant to be generic enough, and
>     allow clients (domain experts) link their own concepts e.g., athletes
>     or politicians using rdfs:sublClassOf the particular concept.
> - [Creative Work Ontology](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/creativework)
>     This is the model we use to express the minimum metadata necessary to express a piece of creative content
>     in the platform. The creative work ontology is continuously evolving
>     based on our clients' requirements. There is a core class in this
>     model, which is the CreativeWork class and properties that support
>     information the LDP clients need to build their products such as
>     title, thumbnail, URL e.t.c.
> - [Programmes Ontology](http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/po)
>     BBC Programmes aims to ensure that every programme brand, series and
>     episode broadcast by the BBC has a permanent, findable web presence.
>     We have developed the Programmes Ontology to expose this data
>     following the Linked Data approach, enabling the interchange of
>     programme information on the Semantic Web.

As an example, the programmes ontology is described at http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/po.  It seems to list some of the kinds of properties you're looking for, and if you attach **.ttl** to the URL, to get http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/po.ttl, you get a nice machine readable representation with content like:

```
po:actor
      rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:comment "Relates a programmes to one of its actors - a person who plays the role of a character" ;
      rdfs:domain po:Programme ;
      rdfs:isDefinedBy po: ;
      rdfs:label "actor" ;
      rdfs:range foaf:Agent ;
      rdfs:subPropertyOf po:credit ;
      vs:term_status "testing" .
```

You could use SPARQL to get a concise listing of properties.  E.g., using sparql.org's query processor:

```sql
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?propety ?ptype
from <http://www.bbc.co.uk/ontologies/po>
where {
  values ?ptype { owl:ObjectProperty owl:DatatypeProperty }
  ?property a ?ptype 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://sparql.org/sparql?query=prefix%20owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fptype%0D%0Afrom%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bbc.co.uk%2Fontologies%2Fpo%3E%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20values%20%3Fptype%20%7B%20owl%3AObjectProperty%20owl%3ADatatypeProperty%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%3Fproperty%20a%20%3Fptype%20%0D%0A%7D&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| property                                         | ptype                |
===========================================================================
| <http://purl.org/ontology/po/broadcasted_on>     | owl:ObjectProperty   |
| <http://purl.org/ontology/po/subject>            | owl:ObjectProperty   |
...
```

Comment: Thanx It is very useful to me......for MusicBrainz anything like this is available ?